# Why doesn't editing work with QComboBox, QDataWidgetMapper, and QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So I'm building the [books](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-books-example.html) example in the Qt documentation, and I can't get editing to work using combo boxes. Basically, I have a QSqlRelationalTableModel mapped to a QTableView, and to several other controls (one of which is a combo box) through a QDataWidgetMapper. Both the table view and the mapper are using a default QSqlRelationalDelegate. The default delegate enables editing, even for fields that are foreign keys into other tables - it creates a combo box right there on the table.

I can edit anything I want in the table, and it works just fine. I can also make edits using the controls mapped through the widget mapper, *except* with the combo box. The combo box populates correctly, and updates correctly when I change my selection in the table, but changing it's value has no effect on the model. However making edits directly in the table (using the combo box created by QSqlRelationalDelegate) does work.

From reading the examples and documentation, it seems like this *should* work. I've even tried implementing a custom delegate, however it's setModelData() method never even gets called when making changes to the combo box (why not?).

Has anyone else had this problem? How did you solve it? I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Relevant sections of code below:

```
# Create the model
self.model = QSqlRelationTableModel(self.tableView)
self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
self.model.setTable('products')

categoryIdx = self.model.fieldIndex('category')

# Set the relation for the category field
self.model.setRelation(categoryIdx, QSqlRelation('categories', 'id', 'name'))

# Populate the model
self.model.select()

# Connect the model and the table
self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
self.tableView.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))

# Set up the controls
self.categoryBox.setModel(self.model.relationModel(categoryIdx))
self.categoryBox.setModelColumn(self.model.relationModel(categoryIdx).fieldIndex('name')

mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
mapper.setModel(self.model)
mapper.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
mapper.addMapping(self.categoryBox, categoryIdx)
... # Add mappings to the other controls
mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.AutoSubmit)

self.tableView.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(mapper.setCurrentModelIndex)
```

I've even tried specifying the currentIndex property like so:

```
mapper.addMapping(self.categoryBox, categoryIdx, 'currentIndex')
```

but that doesn't work either. I'm using PyQt5, FWIW.

Comment: Turns out that I needed to manually connect the combo box's currentIndexChanged() signal to the data widget mapper's submit() slot. Although I'm still not clear on why this is necessary for the combo box and not for the other controls...

Comment: Are you aware that python versions of all Qt examples are included if you [download the source package of PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)? Making them yourself might still be insightful, of course.

Comment: I just run into the same problem. I'm running OS X and I believe the problem occurs because comboboxes do not get the focus in OS X and therefore do not emit the `commitData()` signal of the delegate. My workaround is `combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: delegate.commitData.emit(combobox))`.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks Garrett and Georg Schölly for these posts! I ran into the same issue as well, and could resolve it with your answers. In my case I've made a `QDataWidgetMapper` subclass that makes the required signal-slot connection automatically:

```
class DataWidgetMapper(QDataWidgetMapper):
    def addMapping(self, widget, section, propertyName=None):
        if propertyName is None:
            super().addMapping(widget, section)
        else:
            super().addMapping(widget, section, propertyName)

        if isinstance(widget, QComboBox):
            delegate = self.itemDelegate()
            widget.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: delegate.commitData.emit(widget))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the QComboBox focusPolicy to ClickFocus or StrongFocus (Qt Designer or in code)

```
widget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
```